# Permissions Error in Perl Script for Linux

Tags: linux, perl, permissions

I'm trying to install the Touchmouse server for Linux. The software is a perl script that I have tried to run via terminal, using the perl command. The software I'm trying to run is here: https://github.com/mycroes/touchmoused

This is the output from terminal:

```
:~/Desktop/touchmoused-master$ perl touchmoused
Can't open /dev/uinput: Permission denied at touchmoused line 242.
:~/Desktop/touchmoused-master$ Established under name '<name of computer>'
```

I am new to Linux but have some experience with Terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: When you get a permissions error on *nix, double check the permissions on the file: `ls -l /dev/uinput` shows `crw------- 1 root root`, so only root has read permissions. Run `sudo ./touchmoused` (although it looks like this is supposed to be a daemon so you might want to configure your init system to run it on startup).

Comment: This isn't really a Perl question. What you want to do is ask in a different venue how to start touchmoused as root on boot. However, you may want to look for an alternative: anyone who connects to port 4096 is going to be able to feed keyboard events to your computer. Even a host-based firewall isn't safe, since someone can just hijack the IP of your iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

From the creator of the script:

> Just download it, chmod +x and run it (as root, it needs access to /dev/uinput and it wants to register with avahi).
>   Regards,

http://blog.mycroes.nl/2011/04/touchmoused-logitech-touch-mouse-server.html

Your user won't have permissions for /dev/uinput, also check that /dev/uinput is the correct location for your distribution, the script allows you to override this with the -device flag.

So either make it executable so you don't have to enter 'perl' and then run with sudo or have root run it on startup.